# How to set up a triple intergal with $x, y,$ and $z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use a triple integral to find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=16xy$, $z\ge 0$, $0 \le x \le 5$, $0 \le y \le 4$. I know how to set up the integral for $x$ and $y$ it would be $0$ to $5$ for $x$ and $0$ to $4$ for $y$. How would you set up the integral for $z$? Please show me how you would set it up and what the integral would look like if you can. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the ranges over which to integrate with respect to $x, y$: each will be treated as a fixed value of the inner-integrals. Since $z$ is a function of $x, y$, we'll use set up the integral of that variable to be innermost. The order of integrating over the ranges for variables $x$ and of $y$ does not matter, so we'll arbitrarily select the order for the outermost integrals.

Since we know $x, y \geq 0$, it follows that $z = 16xy \geq 0$ (and we are also given that $z \geq 0$), so we can use the bounds for variable $z$ in terms $x, y$, from lower bound of $z = 0$ to the upper-bound when $z = 16xy$. That permits us to begin computing volume over the range $0 \leq z \leq 16xy$:

$$ \int_{0}^{5}\int_0^4 \int_{0}^{16xy} dz\,dy\,dx = \int_0^5 \int_0^4 16xy \;dy\,dx$$

So evaluating the innermost of the triple integral gives you, essentially, the double integral in terms of $x, y$, since $$\int_0^{16xy} dz \;= \;\;z\;\Big|_0^{16xy} \;=\; 16xy - 0 = 16xy$$

Comment: You're welcome, jain.

Comment: @amWhy: nice feedback :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

In each dimension, you want the acceptable range of that variable.  Each inner integral is taken at a fixed point of the outer variable(s).  You want the range in $z$ corresponding to any given $x$ and $y$.  The minimum is $0$ and the maximum is $16xy$ as this is positive.  So the result is $$\int_{0}^{5}\int_0^4 \int_{0}^{16xy} dzdydx$$